# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0' not found

Tags: java, maven

I try to install maven-checkstyle-plugin, and Idea says what
`Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0' not found`
reporting section in my pom.xml

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

I tried update maven indices, but it doesn't help
where is the error and how to fix it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked the Maven Checkstyle Plugin Releases History and I cannot find an entry for version 3.0.0. I'm not sure where that version value originated, but we can follow up on that. I'd like to start by getting your problem resolved and get you back to a working build status.

The current Maven Checkstyle Plugin release version is: 3.1.1. Please update the version value in your POM to this value, attempt a build, and please let me know how it goes.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0WcVYJJ   I use this article https://www.baeldung.com/checkstyle-java